# Unable to eject expo to react native - tried a fix from another answer (link below) but it still doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to eject expo to bare react-native CLI but I can't because I am not able to enter the android package name when asked. Basically, when I type any android package name and hit enter it just returns a blank value again.

This is where the problem exists
[here's the screenshot of the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh7vh.png)

I tried the workaround for the same problem from here: [Unable to eject expo to react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058283/unable-to-eject-expo-to-react-native)

But the error still exists.

My app.json file is as follows:

```
{
  
  "ios": { "bundleIdentifier": "IOSName", "supportsTablet": true },

  "android": { "package": "AndroidName" },
  
  "expo": {
    "name": "employeeapp",
    "slug": "employeeapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share a link to your repository. also, you may want to use powershell instead of cmd

Comment: Heres the repo https://github.com/BALAJIRAO676/EmployeeApp-ReactNative

Answer (score 0):

you can change the ios and android keys to:

```
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.employeeapp"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.example.empoyeeapp"
    },
```

now when you run it, i suggest using `expo eject --non-ineractive` because your terminal does not appear to support interactive prompts